# Как указать пароль при dump'е базы?

Tags: postgresql, резервное-копирование

Нужно сделать бэкап базы по cron'у

Написал команду

`pg_dump -x -O -U postgres -h localhost db_name > db_backup_name.sql`. Но команда требует ввода пароля.

Как указать пароль в команде?

Comment: можно в конфиге разрешить подключение без пароля для localhost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть другой вариант дампа:

```
pg_dump --dbname=postgresql://user:password@localhost:5432/db_name > db_backup_name.sql
```

Comment: В принципе этот вариант сработал) спасибо

Answer (score 1):

[я бы рекомендовал пользоваться](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.6/libpq-pgpass) `.pgpass`. Permissions запрещяют его просмотр пользователям, отличным от postgres, а при использовании пароля в командной строке любой user увидит его просто запустив `ps`.

для вас он будет выглядеть так:

```
localhost:*:db_name:postgres:ваш пароль, как он есть
```

сохранить его надо в домашней директории с `chmod 600`

Comment: cпасибо, реально нужная вещь